# Invoke Lambda function with request;

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, request, aws-lambda

How to invoke Lambda function using directly AWS API (not aws-sdk) and node.js

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  url: 'https://lambda.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/http/invocations'
, headers: {
'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};
request.post(options, callback);
```

The example returns `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`

Comment: Why not use the AWS SDK? Otherwise, why not expose it via API Gateway first?

Comment: My assumption is "aws-sdk" doing pretty much the same (with http), anyway it's 5.1 mb uncompressed (such big module may be heavy to use I don't know). Not using API gateway due to budget/credits limitations.

Comment: AWS SDK is using your provided IAM credentials to sign the request so that it will be authorized. It is a big pain to do that yourself without the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

`AWS SDK` is doing much more than just plain HTTP request. `AWS SDK HTTP` request contains API key, digital signature and so on. You should stick to using `AWS SDKs` with your code since it's the most efficient way to get things up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the request and provide the proper `Authorization` headers, using appropriate AWS IAM credentials. The process is relatively complex, but I see you are using nodejs, so I will link out to the best npm module for doing request signatures using your credentials + the documentation for DIY request signatures...:

Best module for this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws4

AWS documentation for raw signing HTTP:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Answer (score 0):

```
const params = {
 FunctionName: 'MyLambdaFunction',
    Qualifier: 'my-alias',
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({hello: 'world'})
};

lambda.raw.invoke(params, (err, result) => {
    // handle the result
});

please find code from this link

https://github.com/SamVerschueren/aws-lambda-invoke
```